# how to select distinct data from selected data which has been order by

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

I've been using oracle database and try to get result from using sql

It's like this:

```
select distinct equip_name
from(select equip_name,category_id where ----- order by TO_NUMBER(category_id))
equip_name
|#2 SRC_310K|
|#3 SRC_310K|
|#1 SRC_310K|
|#4 SRC_310K|
```

but result of distinct *equip_name* are not in order by category_id

How can i get ordered data?

Comment: If there are multiple category ids, which one do you want to order by?

Answer (score 0):

You can order by *some* category id by using `group by`:

```
select equip_name
from table t
group by equip_name
order by min(category_id);
```

This orders the equipment by the smallest category assigned to it.

Comment: Sorry my question has missing part, category_id has to be ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(category_id)....... category_id is list of number like 1,2,3,4...

Comment: @SSirius . . . Your comment makes no sense.  Edit the question and add sample data and desired results.